# How do I store a bivy sack?

Tags: storage, bivy-sacks

I bought a BlocVent bivy sack. What’s a good way to store it for a long time? Obviously I’ll dry it after a hike, but is it okay to roll it up and put it into a small stuff sack afterwards? Or should I keep it unrolled, like a sleeping bag or a mat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also sent the question to the manufacturer. They say that all membrane stuff in general is best stored unfolded, freely hanging or lying.

Comment: I don't own a bivy per se, but I store my tents and tarps hanging alongside my sleeping bags.